# how to fix call external domain through angular proxy keep returning index.html

Tags: angular, typescript

my angular app works fine when i run and test it with localhost:4200. when i deployed to web hosting, web hosting server keep returning my app 'index.html' in plaintex and did not call external api. 
i confused why it works when developing time, but deploy to web hosting not.

proxy.conf.json :

```
 {
   "/api": {
     "target": "https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify",
     "secure": true,
     "pathRewrite": {"^/api": ""},
     "changeOrigin": true,
     "logLevel": "debug"
   }
 }
```

my service call function.

```
sendLineNotify(msg: string) {

    let token = "Bearer ----my_token------";

    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded").set("Authorization", token);

    let params = new HttpParams().set("message", msg);
    return this.http.post<string>('api', params, { headers: headers, responseType: 'text' as 'json' }).toPromise().then(r => { 

      console.log(r);
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.error("line say: ", error);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `URL` not this

```
let url = 'https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify';
```

it is

```
let url = './api';
```

Comment: ORBIT: sorry  i tried many times forget delete my url code, however i replaced to 'api' when i call post method. it work fine when running locally, except on hosting server.

Comment: remove your proxy

Comment: i have tried but CORS err issued. that why i use proxy.

Comment: yep in real server you dont want proxy